# SAS separete Dates from one variable

Tags: date, variables, sas

i need to separate every date that I create in the next sentence so I'm able to create a variable for every date.

The next loop create dates in one variable.

```
data _null_;
End_date= /*today()-1;*/ '30JUN2021'd;
call symput('days',intck('day',intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b'), End_date));
End_month=intnx("month",End_date,0,'e');
format End_month End_date ddmmyy10.;
run;


data _null_;
length varnew $30000.;
End_date= /*today()-1;*/ '30JUN2021'd;
do i=0 to &days.;
     if i=0 then do;
          varnew=put(intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b'),ddmmyy10.);
     end;
     else do;
          if intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+i ne intnx("month",intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+i,0,'e') then do;
                varnew= trim(varnew)||" "||put(intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+i,ddmmyy10.);
          end;
          else do;
                varnew= trim(varnew)||" "||put(intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+i,ddmmyy10.)||" "||put(intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+i,mmyys7.);
          end;
     end;
end;
if End_date ne intnx("month",end_date,0,'e') then do;
call symput('varnew',trim(varnew)||" "||put(intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+&days.,mmyys7.)||" "||put(intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+&days.,mmyys7.)||"*");
end;
else do;
call symput('varnew',trim(varnew)||" "||put(intnx("year",End_date,-1,'b')+&days.,mmyys7.)||"*");
end;
run;

%put --&varnew.--;
```

That looks like

```
--01/01/2020 02/01/2020 03/01/2020 04/01/2020 05/01/2020 06/01/2020 07/01/2020 08/01/2020 09/01/2020 10/01/2020 11/01/2020 
12/01/2020 13/01/2020 14/01/2020 15/01/2020 16/01/2020 17/01/2020 18/01/2020 19/01/2020 20/01/2020 21/01/2020 22/01/2020 23/01/2020 
24/01/2020 25/01/2020 26/01/2020 27/01/2020 28/01/2020 29/01/2020 30/01/2020 31/01/2020 01/2020 01/02/2020 02/02/2020 03/02/2020 
04/02/2020 05/02/2020 06/02/2020
```

So what I want is to create for every date a variable to look like

| VAR1        | VAR2        | VAR3        |

|-------------| ------------|-------------|

| 01/01/2020  | 02/01/2020  | 03/01/2020  |

Comment: You talk about variables, but both of your data steps are not writing any datasets.  Are you trying to create a dataset (which is where variables live). Or is the goal just to create some macro variables (aka symbols)?  If symbols then do you want to store the actual date value (number of days) or the formatted text strings that humans would recognize?

Comment: Please describe in words the series of dates you are trying to create.  Reading between the lines it appears you want to format the date strings in DMY order.  Is there some particular reason you need that order?  It will cause many humans to confuse the 3rd of January for March 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this all in one step. Set your end date and start date, then loop through and create a macro variable for each one. The first argument of `call symputx()` accepts functions as well. We'll create a counter for each variable, then append it to the name `var`.

The `output` statement and dataset created are not needed and are here for descriptive purposes only.

```
data dates;
    end_date   = '30JUN2021'd;
    start_date = intnx('year', end_date, -1, 'B');
    
    do date = start_date to end_date;
        i = date-start_date+1;

        output;
 
        /* Dynamically create new macro variables named var1, var2, etc. */
        call symputx(cats('var', i), put(date, ddmmyys10.) );
    end;

    format end_date start_date date ddmmyys10.;
run;

%put var1: &var1;
%put var2: &var2;
%put var3: &var3;
```

Output:

```
var1: 01/01/2020
var2: 02/01/2020
var3: 03/01/2020
```

If you're trying to create data step variables where you have one variable for each date, you can do a similar thing with arrays. You can't dynamically assign an array size, so we'll set our end/start dates and array size using macro variables.

```
/* Create date constants for array */
%let end_date   = '30JUN2021'd;
%let start_date = %sysfunc(intnx(year, %sysfunc(putn(&end_date, 8.)), -1, B));
%let n_dates    = %eval(%sysfunc(putn(&end_date., 8.)) - &start_date.+1);

/* Generate dates for each array variable */
data dates;
    end_date   = &end_date.;
    start_date = &start_date.;
    
    array var[&n_dates.];

    do date = start_date to end_date;
        i = date-start_date+1;
        var[i] = date;
    end;

    format start_date end_date var: ddmmyys10.;
run;
```

Output:

```
var1        var2        var3
01/01/2020  02/01/2020  03/01/2020
```

Comment: You don't need the `strip()` function call.  First the formatted value does not contain any leading or trailing spaces, and second `call symputx()` automatically removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Yep that's correct. I forgot that `symputx` does do that. I tend to do it out of habit to be safe.